# How do you display a list item image with SPServices? (Rather than displaying the URL)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, spservices

I'm currently using SPServices to retrieve information from a list and present it on the page. I've retrieved the metadata correctly,and presented it on the page. However, when attempting to display an image, I receive the URL, rather than the image. How is it possible to display the list item image rather than the URL of the image?

The method below simply displays the URL of the image.

```
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {    

                var itemImage = $(this).attr('ows_Image');
                var itemName = $(this).attr('ows_Title');




                newElement +=                       
                            '<div class="container">
                                '<div class="item-name">' + itemName + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="item-image">' + itemImage + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
```

I have also tried the following;

```
<div class="item-image">' + '<img src="itemImage"/>' + '</div>'
```

and other such variations. This doesn't return a URL of the image, but rather a "broken image" icon (provided by the browser).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just render an image tag with the link as Source?

```
<img src="{YOUR RETRIEVED URL}" />
```

UPDATE: This should do the trick

```
<div class="item-image">' + '<img src="' + itemImage + '"/>' + '</div>'
```

The difference is that you are basically just using "itemImage" as the source of the image, rather than the value of the string variable named itemImage.

Comment: Hi Robert - Thanks for the response. I got close by having a similar approach of <div class="item-image">' + '<img src="itemImage"/>' + '</div>'. This shows an image placeholder icon, but not the image from the list item.

Comment: then I recommend you to inspect the output and see what is incorrect in the src and hence why the image can not be found.

Comment: Thanks again for the response - I have attempted a number of variations, which is why I am here... ;)

Comment: OK, can you please update your post with an example of how the URL you retreive looks like?

Comment: OK - I've updated this the best I can. Simply put, the first attempt simply shows the URL of the image. The actual URL text. Nothing else. The second approach displays a broken image icon. Unfortunately, i'm unable to be clearer than this :)

Comment: Se my updated answer

Comment: @RobertLindgren - you may want to edit the answer to make the error more clear. Basically the asker code was just using the string "imageurl" as the url, while your sample will correctly use the url value. ^_^